# Two [columns] meanings

Tags: discussion, tagging

I was trying to find a comprehensive question about best practices to make a multicolumn document, but it looks like [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) encompasses both table columns and text columns!

- Table columns

  - 378: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)
  - 185: [Adding space between columns in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/adding-space-between-columns-in-a-table)
- Text columns

  - 137: [Page-wide table in two-column mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode)
  - 107: [Creating two columns in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228271/creating-two-columns-in-beamer)

Perhaps these should be separated?

Comment: Kind of unrelated to your question, but "a comprehensive question about best practices" is not usually on-topic on this site.

Comment: @Teepeemm I was thinking like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex Although this is pretty extreme

Answer (score 8):

The `columns` tag description says:

> {columns} is specifically about columns in {tables} (though often the
> latter tag will suffice). If your question is about {two-column}
> documents or the {multicol} package, use the respective tag instead.

Hence, `columns` is for tables, sometimes it is wrongly used for two-column documents.

When you see a post with the wrong tag, you may edit it and correct it. There is the button "Edit tags" just next to the tags.

Comment: Actually, at my rep on this site, I have to `Edit` all together

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Editing a post, you also earn reputation, and you will soon be able to edit only tags.

Comment: If `columns` became a synonym of a main tag `table-columns`, then this mistake would be easier to spot. Just a suggestion though.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I tried to suggest it as a synonym but it fails because the tag should exist before suggesting it as a synonym. I'll ask a moderator.